# How do build parallel binary tree in MPI?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, binary-tree

I want to build a binary tree from 4 processors in MPI. At root, all processors work together, next level I divide the processors into 2 groups and in this way at leaf each processor is responsible to build local tree.

I used mpi_comm_slpit to split current communicator into 2 parts. But the problem is how do I keep track parent-child relationship? like serial programming, we use pointer to point left-right child? How can I handle it in MPI? Thanks.

```
     [1-4]        <-- root
 [1-2]   [2-3] 
[1] [2] [3] [4]
```

Comment: You're probably making things far too complicated by splitting the default communicator.  Draw a picture of a 4-node binary tree, label the nodes 0-3.  Declare that to be the canonical way of decomposing a binary tree across 4 processors, write a function so that a processor, knowing it's own rank, can determine where in the binary tree it is.  Carry on communicating.

Comment: Thanks. I got your point.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to divide the communicator. In a binary tree the work is 2^n where n is the level. Depending on if you are traversing upwards or downwards you will have increase in idle processors or increase in number of processors (try imagining this). So for example if you start from top could divide your work done by root into 2. Now W1 to root (proc0) and W2 to (proc1). Next step proc0 and proc1 divide W1 and W2 into 2 parts. W11 to proc0, W12 to proc3, W21 to proc1 W22 to proc4 and so on ....

Hope this helps. Playing with communicators would complicate things ;)